# Silverlight datagrid in usercontrol does not support sorting

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

If i create a datagrid on a silverlight page and bind it to a domaindatasource / ria services then i automatically get features like sorting/resizing/reordering of columns.
When i copy the exact same code into a usercontrol then the column headers lose these features. Is there something obvious im missing here?

Edit: I noticed that when i remove the associated pager beneath my grid, sorting gets enabled. The only question is why..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright.. the problem was that the pager was positioned on top of the grid (even though it looks like its positioned below the grid, its boundaries actually stretch across the whole grid), hence stealing all mouse and keyboard input. To resolve this one could set the z index of the pager to 0 and the z index of the grid to 1 (or perhaps use a stackpanel?)